# local IP after gethostbyname()

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

How do I get the local IP address before using `sendto()` that is going to be used for the transmission to a remote host?

If I understand correctly, it should be known already after `gethostbyname(remoteHostname)` call.

I need this for including the local IP in the transmitted packet (127.0.0.1 wouldn't make sense). UDP is used.

Comment: Why do you need your local IP ? the IP stack of your operating system will insert the local and correct source address. You ususally need the remote IP address , so you know which address to send the packet to.

Comment: It is a protocol requirement. It is like agent IP in an SNMP trap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `getsockname(2)` on a connected UDP socket; the stack would need to perform a fair amount of routing to connect the socket, sufficient to know which local address would be used once packets are sent or received.

Comment: I hoped that the routing done to get the local IP by gethostname was enough. The message itself is trap like and therefore the socket is not "connected" before transmission (as it might be the very first transmission).

Comment: @Noros That's ok, you can just call connect() anyway, before you send that first message. For UDP, connect() is just internal to the local machine/your process. No messages are exchanged with the remote party. (but in the case you need to send to many different remote addresses, you then have to create a new socket and connect it for each remote address - unless you absolutely know your machine will only ever have 1 IP address)

Answer (score 1):

You can call connect() on the socket first. UDP ofcourse is not connection oriented, but connect will just register the socket to only send to the given remote IP address, so you can e.g. just use send() instead of sendto()

However, this allows you to call getsockname() on the socket, and at least under Linux this will fetch the local address the socket uses. Here's an example, you can extract the info in the print_local_addr() here and use that info in your SNMP trap. (the bind() call is only needed if you want a fixed source port too)

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void diep(char *s)
{
  perror(s);
  exit(1);
}

void print_local_addr(int s)
{
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof my_addr;
    if(getsockname(s,(struct sockaddr*)&my_addr,&len) == -1)
      diep("getsockname");
    //print the local address of the socket that will be used when
    //sending datagrams to the "connected" peer.
    printf("local addr %s:%u\n",inet_ntoa(my_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(my_addr.sin_port));
}

int main(void)
{
  struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
  int s;

  if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
    diep("socket");

  memset(&si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
  memset(&si_other, 0, sizeof(si_me));
  //bind to local port 4567
  si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
  si_me.sin_port = htons(4567);
  si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  //"connect" google's DNS server at 8.8.8.8 , port 4567
  si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
  si_other.sin_port = htons(4567);
  si_other.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("8.8.8.8");
  if(connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&si_other,sizeof si_other) == -1)
    diep("connect");
  print_local_addr(s);
  close(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Info grabbed from: http://www.suite101.com/content/socket-programming-gethostbyname-a19557

As you said, `localhost` doesn't work.  Instead, look up your hostname first, and pass that to `gethostbyname`.

```
char hostName[255];
gethostname(hostName, 255);

struct hostent* host_entry;
host_entry=gethostbyname(hostName);

char* localIP;
szLocalIP = inet_ntoa (*(struct in_addr*)*host_entry->h_addr_list);
```

Should this not be suitable, you can also do a DNS lookup, do a WMI query, or look it up in the registry.

Comment: How do I know the IP found such way is the one that is going to be used for transmission to a given remote IP (that is resolved by gethostbyname)?